# Magento Extra Totral at checkout display issue

Tags: magento

I have Added one Extra total on one page checkout .I had added custom title with some tooltip and it was working fine. but since i did the magento upgrade , it shows html tags.

[image]

Comment: Some information bout how did you added your order total, version of Magneto before and after upgrade would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using magento v1.7+

Take a look at your total template /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/total/default.phtml

Magento is escaping html using $this->escapeHtml()

```
<?php if ($this->getRenderingArea() == $this->getTotal()->getArea()): ?><strong><?php endif; ?>
   <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getTotal()->getTitle()); ?>
<?php if ($this->getRenderingArea() == $this->getTotal()->getArea()): ?></strong><?php endif; ?>
```

Take a look at /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php

```
public function escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags = null)
{
    return $this->helper('core')->escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags);
}
```

To fix this you can either remove `$this->escapeHtml()`or `$this->escapeHtml($this->getTotal()->getTitle(), array('span','a'))`

Comment: that array will allow the html tags that are specified not beescaped?

Comment: Yes, it will not escape those tags